# Set minimum password length in Rails .erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to add a minimum password length rule in this .erb file I recently was tasked to work on, but received little information about how all of this is configured and what tools are being used. In the .erb file there exists some javascript where on validation there are some rules set, I see that I need to add. Here is what the javascript looks like:

```
$("#form").steps({
        ...
    }).validate({
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    element.before(error);
                },
                rules: {
                    confirm: {
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    }
                }
            });
```

I see that I need to add a new rule for the password, probably something like:

```
password: {
    ???
}
```

But like I said I don't exactly know what resource is controlling all of this. Is it devise, base rails, etc.? I mainly just need to figure out what this is so that I can search using the proper terms.

Comment: There may be a turbolinks issue even if the root problem is solved (i'm assuming by adding the password key with a value of "required" that is referenced in confirm). Can you show us how are you loading the JS?

Comment: I would steer away from password validation in the front end (ok for length checking but frontend values can be manipulated by the user). Check the Gemfile for Devise, have a look in the User model to see if there is anything in there..

Comment: Looks like you could be using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/) in which case add a rule for your password field with minlength set `rules: { password: { required: true, minlength: 2 } }`